# What software can I use for gas adsorption calculations?

Tags: software, software-recommendations, condensed-matter

We are from a new research group working on matter modelling. Currently our work has focused mainly on classical Molecular Dynamics (MD), Lattice Dynamics (LD) and ab-initio methods. For  these, we have been using [LAMMPS](https://www.lammps.org/), [Gulp](http://gulp.curtin.edu.au/gulp/), [SIESTA](https://departments.icmab.es/leem/siesta/Documentation/index.html), [Quantum Espresso](https://www.quantum-espresso.org/) and [CP2K](https://www.cp2k.org/).

Although we are currently studying the thermoelectric properties of semiconductor materials, we would like to expand our research focus to other areas **such as gas adsorption as well**.

***What software can we use for gas adsorption?*** I am particularly interested in the ability to simulate larger system sizes, acceleration methods, interoperability with other third party tools, ease of use, etc. We are looking at both commercial as well as free packages.

Thanks

Comment: +1. But can you tell us specifically what you want to do? "Ab ibitio methods" is far too broad (Gaussian and VASP use *ab initio* methods but for extremely different problems). Also perhaps narrow this down to just MD or just ab-initio, etc., and ask each question separately 1 week apart. That's my advice for the best result.

Comment: I think Nike brings up some good point here, the question is very broad and boarders on being too opinion based. I think there is a core of this that would make a good question (or several good questions), but I'm closing it for now until we can edit it down to a more specific question.

Comment: @NikeDattani thanks for the advice. I have edited the question, but I'm not sure whether the scope is sufficiently narrowed down. Please feel free to reedit and assist in narrowing this down.

Comment: The process to reopen usually involves a community vote, rather than just deleting and reposting the question. While the question has two votes to reopen currently, I still think it's too broad. Its asking about comparing types of software across a variety of subdisciplines based on their ability to solve several different, very general problems, without much direction about what you need out of them (e.g. faster, lots of methods implemented, easy to use).

Comment: I think narrowing to one type (e.g. gas absorption, saving the others for other questions) and maybe some specific features you would like (speed, interoperability), that would help. We also do have several questions generally comparing different electronic structure and MD programs, so these may already address some of your questions about what these programs can do and do well.

Comment: @Tyberius thanks for the clarification. I have edited the question.

Comment: I have reopened the post, I think it's sufficiently narrowed down. Be sure to check out some of the other questions comparing programs: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/1535/what-are-some-open-source-all-electron-dft-alternatives-to-wien2k, https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4538/what-is-a-good-replacement-for-gaussian,

Comment: I've narrowed it down to only gas adsorption, which turns out to be what Tyberius also recommended in his comment back on 17 November. The question was far too broad before. As for gas adsorption, I assume you're referring to the adsorption of a gas phase substance onto a solid surface? Is this not something that the some of the software you already mentioned, can do?

Comment: Yes. But I am looking at other available options to do this.

Comment: If it's in porous materials, you should check out [RASPA](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/08927022.2015.1010082). GitHub code [here](https://github.com/iRASPA/RASPA2).

Comment: @AndrewRosen we are looking at possible software package options. Would you please be kind enough to add this as an answer. We are trying to understand the opinions of those who use different software packages so that we can make an informed decision on which one to choose.

Comment: You see what difference narrowing down the question makes?

Comment: @NikeDattani the bounty doesn't hurt either. In this case, it put it at the top of the home page, so I saw the question. Seeing the question is always a good start. Although, it was probably an edit or some other activity that put it at the top, I don't know if the bounty does that alone...

Comment: @Wesley the bounty put it at the top of the page 6 days ago (then it fell down again), but my recent edit (which narrowed down the scope) put it ***back*** to the top yesterday.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can look at [RASPA](https://iraspa.org/raspa/) by Snurr et al. (Dubbledam, Calero, Vlugt). It is made for gas adsorption and other simulations. They used to have a Fortran version called Music, but this is a revamped edition written in C.

[GOMC](https://github.com/GOMC-WSU/GOMC) is a GPU optimized Monte Carlo code for many things, adsorption is one of them. Likely a good starting place.

[Cassandra](http://sites.nd.edu/maginn-group/cassandra/) by Maginn et al. is also used for gas adsorption in crystalline materials. It is Monte Carlo. This also has interface to the [MoSDeF](https://mosdef.org/) consortium.

You can also look at [Towhee](http://towhee.sourceforge.net/). You can do gas adsorption via grand canonical simulations, and probably others. This used to be Monte Carlo, and I think still is. It may also do Molecular Dynamics.

You can also use [DL Monte](https://www.ccp5.ac.uk/DL_MONTE), another Monte Carlo software, for gas adsorption.

Cory Simon's group also has software written in Julia for gas adsorption [Simon Ensemble Git Repo](https://github.com/SimonEnsemble)

If you are after a program that can interface, I would lean towards Cassandra or RASPA since Cassandra has an interface to MoSDeF. There is a Monte Carlo code called [BRiCK](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00334) written by several authors involved in RASPA, and as such, there is a high probability of interfacing the two. Unfortunately for RASPA, while I have not used it myself, I know people who have, and they almost went insane :S

Unfortunately adsorption is largely done via Monte Carlo folks, and Monte Carlo software has not garnered the attention that Molecular Dynamics software has, so you won't find really high end software comparable to Gromacs/OpenMM/LAMMPS/AMBER/NAMD etc.

Comment: Thanks for the very insightful answer. I'll certainly look into these packages.

Comment: Most programs are in Fortran. Once the big coders come to play in Monte Carlo/Adsorption, we will see some nice C/C++ codes, I am sure. The older school fortraners have laid out some pretty decent algorithms though... we just need dedicated coders to make them super fast and user friendly

Comment: @PBH I added GOMC just now, you should take a look at their code. I have never used it, but the peek I took looked promising. It says it does adsorption and many other things.

Comment: Thank you for the addition. GOMC indeed looks promising. I'll check that out as well.